# uv_fs_open: flags and mode on Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, libuv, fcntl

From the [official documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/fs.html#c.uv_fs_open) we have the following signature for `uv_fs_open`:

```
int uv_fs_open(uv_loop_t* loop, uv_fs_t* req, const char* path, int flags, int mode, uv_fs_cb cb);
```

And it is said that it is equivalent to [`open(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open).

From the most accredited [tutorial](https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/filesystem.html) I've found on the web, we have this (emphasis mine):

> flags and mode are standard Unix flags. **libuv takes care of converting to the appropriate Windows flags**.

Because of that, I thought that the following statement would have worked both on Linux and Windows:

```
uv_fs_open(my_loop, my_req,  my_filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU, my_callback);
```

Actually, it works just fine on Linux.
Anyway, on Windows I receive the following errors:

> 'O_RDWR': undeclared identifier
>   'O_CREAT': undeclared identifier
>   'S_IRWXU': undeclared identifier

Is it the expected result (and thus the tutorial is wrong)?
What should I do to have a call to `uv_fs_open` that just works on both the platforms?
What are the values for *flags* and *mode* to be used on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use `uv_fs_open` on Windows, users have to:

- include `fcntl.h` explicitly, because `uv-win.h` doesn't include it (see [this](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1127) issue for further details)
- use `_O_CREAT`, `_O_RDWR_` and so on instead of `O_CREAT`, `O_RDWR` and the others (see the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx) for further details)

Something similar applies to the *mode* and details on the available constants can be found in the linked documentation.